# How to include data from point in Highcharts xAxis label?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to include some extra data from my points in the xAxis  label of a Highcharts line chart.

I'm creating my points like this.  xAxis is 'datetime' type, and I'm using custom tickPositions (this part works fine).

```
for (row of results) {
    var point = {x:Date.parse(row.time), y:row.value, magicNumber:row.ID};
    data_series.data.push(point);
    chartConfig.xAxis.tickPositions.push(Date.parse(row.time));
}
```

In the tooltip I'm able to do the following (this works):

```
tooltip: {          
    formatter: function() {
        return 'ID: ' + this.point.magicNumber + '  Value:' + this.point.y.toFixed(3);
    },
},
```

How do I do the equivalent in the xAxis formatter?  Not clear from [the docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter) if this is possible.

```
 xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            rotation: 90,    
            formatter: function () {
                var ID = **What goes here to obtain magicNumber?** 

                var datetime = new Date(this.value);
                return ID.toString() + ' ' + datetime.toISOString();
            }
        },

        tickPositions: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `console.log(this);` should give you a hint if my solution doesn't works.

```
 xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        rotation: 90,    
        formatter: function () {
            console.log(this);
            var ID = this.chart.series[0].data[this.pos].magicNumber;

            var datetime = new Date(this.value);
            return ID.toString() + ' ' + datetime.toISOString();
        }
    },

    tickPositions: []
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately on a 'datetime' axis, this.pos is a Date not an index.

Answer (score 0):

Both formatters has different context, so one way out of that is by iterate on every point of your data (inside of the `xAxis.labels.formatter` function), find the point which has the same `x` as `this.value`, and assign it to some variable. It should be enough, but there is a likelihood of a returning empty object, when none of points won't fit to the tick value.

```
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
          formatter() {
            var points = this.chart.userOptions.series[0].data

            var sameTimestampPoint = points.filter(p => p.x === this.value)[0]
            var magicValue = sameTimestampPoint ? sameTimestampPoint.magicValue : ""

            return magicValue + '<br/>' + this.value 
          }
        }

      }
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/2r8z5wny/